# How to put Custom fields to XMPP vCard Android/SMACK

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, vcf-vcard

I am currently developing a chat application and I am using the following Vcard to store User information.

```
public void run() {
VCard vcard = new VCard();
vcard.setJabberId(xmppConnection.getUser());
vcard.setNickName(user.getChatId());
vcard.setFirstName(user.getUsername());
vcard.setPhoneHome("CELL", user.getMobileNo()); }
```

In addition to the above values I want to add new fields to the Vcard like

```
vcard.setNotificationType(user.getNotType())
vcard.setAlerts(user.getAlerts())
```

Is this possible? If so please help me on how to do it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, you seem to want to store configuration preference in Vcard. VCard are intended to be public and can be retrieved by others.

Comment: That is not a problem as long as I can save those data. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible, but you are using a feature for a need that is very different to what it is intended. Why don't you use XMPP private storage ? http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0049.html

Comment: But the simplicity is there. We can request a Vcard, save a vcard easily and get the common fields like Name, ID, Phone no. etc simply. I'am not saying what you suggest is bad but this way its is simpler right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's an old question but maybe someone would need the answer..

You can use `vCard.setField(String field, String value)`

For Example :

```
vcard.setField("NotificationType", user.getNotType());
```

And to get it back :

```
vcard.getField("NotificationType");
```

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^